# how to use spring data neo4j search for fulltext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am learning spring data neo4j and spring .I want to search fulltext,for example I have  three Movies (sky,sky1,sky2),when i search "sky",it return sky,sky1,sky2.firt i use repository below

```
package com.oberon.fm.repository;
@Repository
     public interface MovieRepository extends GraphRepository<Movie> {
     Movie findById(String id);
     Page<Movie> findByTitleLike(String title, Pageable page);
}
```

My controller below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/movies", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=text/html")
public String findMovies(Model model, @RequestParam("q") String query) {
    log.debug("1");
    if (query != null && !query.isEmpty()) {
        Page<Movie> movies =movieRepository.findByTitleLike(query, new PageRequest(0, 20));
        model.addAttribute("movies", movies.getContent());
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("movies", Collections.emptyList());
    }
    model.addAttribute("query", query);
    addUser(model);
    return "/movies/list";
}
```

these does not work well,i think somewhere might be wrong,but i dont know,if you have any idea,tell me thanks! by the way,it throw exception java.lang.NullPointerException.
My Movie entity

```
@NodeEntity
public class Movie {
@GraphId
Long nodeId;

@Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "id")
String id;

@Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "search")
String title;

String description;

@RelatedTo(type = "DIRECTED", direction = INCOMING)
Set<Director> directors;

@RelatedTo(type = "ACTS_IN", direction = INCOMING)
Set<Actor> actors;

@RelatedToVia(type = "ACTS_IN", direction = INCOMING)
Iterable<Role> roles;

@RelatedToVia(type = "RATED", direction = INCOMING)
@Fetch
Iterable<Rating> ratings;
private String language;
private String imdbId;
private String tagline;
private Date releaseDate;
private Integer runtime;
private String homepage;
private String trailer;
private String genre;
private String studio;
private Integer version;
private Date lastModified;
private String imageUrl;
```

Comment: share the exception, what does your `Movie` look like? What does your `query` value look like? You should use @Indexed(type=fulltext) on title.

Comment: the query value is "sky",i have three movies(sky,sky1,sky2),and i want when i query "sky",it return  (sky,sky1,sky2),am i lose anything,whether i need a cypher?these are all my code.i dont know how i search db only use Page<Movie> findByTitleLike(String title, Pageable page);tell me   Michael thank you very much